# rails server command doesn't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run the rails server on windows instance (I am using gitbash). I already install ruby (1.9.3), rails(4.2.0) and gem (1.8.29). I have took a screen shots of my error and my Gemfiles so you guys can look at it. I dig into the error and it seems like PTY files which are required on the slave.rb files is not supported on the windows! Does anyone know the way around this problem?
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do ``bundle install``?

Comment: pty gem is currently not available in Windows. Not sure if/when it will ever be. Strongly suggest you use a Linux OS something like Mint if you are just getting started. You will run into a lot of Windows limitations and differences. Also you will be hosting on a linux distro so good to get familiar with the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this for the time being comment out the web-console gem as this has reference to the pty gem but please take note of my comment on your question

```
# gem 'web-console'
```

You might then want to run bundle install again